# Firebase checkin system schema

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to create a checking system using firebase, the way it would work is that it would take the business user uid and the then person checking in uid.

The database looks something like this :
[image]

Would this work or is there no way to concurrently get two uids?

**EDIT**

In my haste I forgot to add the code that I tried:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if(user) {
        var buisnesscheckedin = db.ref("checkedin/" + user.uid)

        checkinButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault()

            buisnesscheckedin.push({
                status: 'true'

            })
            console.log("Checked In")
        })

    }
    else {
        window.location.href = 'index.html'
    }

})
```

This is what I tried but the problem is that I want to be able to get the uid associated with the business instead of using the consumers uid first.

So the path should look this:
`checkedin/buisness_uid/consumer_uid/`

Comment: where is your code ? what did you try ?

Comment: Added my code. I am not sure if it is possible to grab the buisness_uid

Comment: How does your app know what business the user is checking in to?